# How do I set the starting state of a Radio Button

Tags: android

I cannot figure oyt how to set the starting state of my radio button.  Now it always starts with the same state, (the first radio button declared in the xm -radioOn file.

here is the xml file code

```
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioOn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="On" 
        android:checked="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioOff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Off" />

</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Its a bit unclear. You want to decide the initial state on runtime?

Answer (score 3):

In code:

```
radio1.setChecked(true);
```

or in xml

In the RadioGroup using :

```
android:checkedButton="id_button_to_check"
```

or in the RadioButton :

```
android:checked="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `RadioGroup`, add this parameter:

```
android:checkedButton="@+id/radioOn"
```